# Regex get last 2 characters pipe not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm creating a regex expression to get the variables passed to a JavaScript constructor.

The input is always going to follow along these lines:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

And the regex I plan to use to strip out the unnecessary parts is:

```
(^app.use\()|(..$)
```

The first part of the regex gets everything up to the first parenthesis, and the it's supposed to pipe it to another expression which gets the last 2 characters of the string.

My issue is that it seems to be ignoring the second regex. I tried a few other expressions in the second part and they worked, but this one isn't.

What am I doing wrong?

**Regex example on Regex101:** https://regex101.com/r/jV9eH6/3

**UPDATE:**

This is **not** a duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

My question is about a specific issue with a regex, not about replacing one string with another in JavaScript.

Comment: As you can see here, I have the correct regex for getting the last 2 characters https://regex101.com/r/aE7fH1/1

Comment: @torazaburo the duplicate flag is not correct. My question is about a specific regex issue, whereas the one you flagged as a duplicate is about replacing one string with another in JavaScript. Their two totally different issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use multiline modifier. Whenever anchors `^`, `$` are used in your regex then feel free to add multi-line modifier `m`.

```
/(^app.use\()|(..$)/gm
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jV9eH6/4)

Comment: Welcome to the regex World :-)